# Remove cell borders

Tags: excel, applescript

I'm having trouble using Applescript to remove cell borders in a table of data. 
I'm starting out with a spreadsheet that contains data in C15:K31. Each of these cells has a border around it. All I want to do is insert a column at index 4 (column D) and then set each of the cells in column D to not have any borders. I included a repeat to look at every cell in column D, but ideally I would simply remove the formatting all at once, without the repeat.

Any thoughts?  My code is below:

tell application "Microsoft Excel"

```
activate workbook
try
    set maxCount to count of sheets of active workbook
    set sheetCounter to 1
    repeat maxCount times
        activate object worksheet sheetCounter
        set theWorksheetName to name of worksheet sheetCounter of active workbook
        if theWorksheetName contains "gap" then
                insert into range column 4 of active sheet
                set column width of column 4 of active sheet to 7.5
                set color index of interior object of column 4 to 0

                set startFormatHere to range "D1" of active sheet
                set nextRow to 1
                repeat 20 times
                    set formatCell to (get offset startFormatHere row offset nextRow)
                    set formatHere to (get address of formatCell)
                    set cellRange to range formatHere
```

--None of the below attempts have worked to remove border lines

```
                    --clear contents range "D2" of active sheet of active workbook 
                    --tell border object of range "D2"
                    --set {line style, line weight, weight, visible} to {None, 0, 0, false}
                    --end tell

                    --set border of range "D2" to false
                    --set weight of (get border of cellRange which border edge bottom) to None
                    --set line style of border object of range "D2" to line style none                  

                    --set line weight of cellRange to 0

                    set nextRow to nextRow + 1
                end repeat
            end repeat
            set sheetCounter to sheetCounter + 1
        else
            set sheetCounter to sheetCounter + 1
        end if
    end repeat
end try
```

end tell

Answer (score 2):

You need the `get border` command --> `get border (a range) which border (an enumeration)`, can be one of the following:

### inside horizontal, inside vertical, diagonal down, diagonal up, edge bottom, ‌edge left, ‌edge right, ‌edge top, ‌border bottom, border left, ‌border right, ‌border top

---

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    activate workbook
    set maxCount to count of sheets of active workbook
    repeat with sheetCounter from 1 to maxCount
        activate object worksheet sheetCounter
        set theWorksheetName to name of worksheet sheetCounter of active workbook
        if theWorksheetName contains "gap" then
            insert into range column 4 of active sheet
            set column width of column 4 of active sheet to 7.5
            set color index of interior object of column 4 to 0

            set myRange to range "D1:D20" of active sheet
            set myBorders to {border top, border bottom, border left, border right}
            repeat with i from 1 to 4
                set theBorder to get border myRange which border (item i of myBorders)
                set line style of theBorder to line style none
            end repeat
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```