# How can you remove all borders in a worksheet?

Tags: excel, macos, applescript, border

In AppleScript and Excel I can remove a border from a cell with something like:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    set myRange to range "B2:B2" of active sheet
    set myBorders to {border top, border bottom, border left, border right}
    repeat with i from 1 to 4
        set theBorder to get border myRange which border (item i of myBorders)
        set line style of theBorder to line style none
    end repeat
end tell
```

learned from [Remove cell borders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32279471/remove-cell-borders) but I'm having issues trying to remove all borders from a worksheet without having to step through each column and row.  I've figured out how to get the active sheet with:

```
set activeSheet to worksheet (get name of active sheet) of workbook (get name of active workbook)
```

and when researching the documentation I see:

```
autoshape line callout one no border
autoshape line callout two no border
autoshape line callout three no border
autoshape line callout four no border
```

but I can't seem to figure out how to remove all borders without stepping into each column and row.  From my searches I found "[How do I use AppleScript to clear a range of cells in excel 2008](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=28532)" but that didn't work.  Is there any easier way to remove all borders in a worksheet?

Comment: No I want all borders and lines around cells to be removed.

Comment: The equivalent through excel is selecting the entire sheet and going to borders and selection of no border

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could access the used range of the active sheet to remove all borders from that range.

```
 tell application "Microsoft Excel"
     set usedRange to used range of active sheet
     set myBorders to {border top, border bottom, border left, border right}
     repeat with i from 1 to 4
         set theBorder to get border usedRange which border (item i of myBorders)
         set line style of theBorder to line style none
     end repeat
 end tell
```